# Removing all legend entries except one in LayoutItemLegend using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend, qgis-print-layouts

For my QGIS Plugin want to remove all legend entries in my layoutItemLegend exept one entries (chiro_layer). I would like to browse all of my legend entries and delete this one if it does not match the layer I want to keep in my legend. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
chiro_layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Data/ACT_CHIRO.shp', 'Activité Chiroptères', 'ogr')
haies_layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Data/HAIES.shp', 'Typologie des haies', 'ogr')
chiro_layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Styles/Pipkuh_A.qml')
haies_layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Styles/Haies.qml')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([chiro_layer, haies_layer])

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout_document = QDomDocument()
layout_url = open('C:/Desktop/print_layout.qpt')
layout_content = layout_url.read()
layout_url.close()
layout_document.setContent(layout_content)
layout.loadFromTemplate(layout_document, QgsReadWriteContext())
project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)
legend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)

for layer in legend.model() :
    if layer != chiro_layer :
        legend.model().removeLayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exact answer but you can try below standalone version to sort out your issue. It worked (tested) considering layer is at root level, not nested (may work for nested layer but untested case on my side)

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('layoutname')

layer = iface.activeLayer()
legend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
model = legend.model()
model.rootGroup().removeLayer(layer)
legend.refresh()
```

FYI, I sort out the issue because I got an error when calling `legend.model().removeLayer` as it's not an available method whereas `legend.model().rootGroup().removeLayer` exists and do the job.